# External log4j config does not work in Spring Boot

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, log4j2, netflix-zuul

I'm working with Spring Boot(war packaging), Zuul and log4j, my dependencies are set as spring documentation says.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I'm working with a shared library so my dependencies have provided scope.

The problem here is when I put my log4j2.yml config in my classpath (resources folder) all works fine, but when my config is outside application, it does not work (only create log files).

```
logging:
  config: ../path/log4j2.yml
```

My server logs show me this:

```
DEBUG Started configuration YamlConfiguration[location=../path/log4j2.yml] 
OK.
TRACE Stopping YamlConfiguration[location=../path/log4j2.yml]...
TRACE YamlConfiguration notified 4 ReliabilityStrategies that config will be 
stopped.
TRACE YamlConfiguration stopping 3 LoggerConfigs.
TRACE YamlConfiguration stopping root LoggerConfig.
TRACE YamlConfiguration notifying ReliabilityStrategies that appenders will 
be stopped.
TRACE YamlConfiguration stopping remaining Appenders.
TRACE YamlConfiguration stopped 3 remaining Appenders.
TRACE YamlConfiguration cleaning Appenders from 4 LoggerConfigs.
```

Additional to this, when I don't use SLF4J (for example apache commons logging), it works!